# On conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I need some help with the following problem:

Let X be a continuos random variable that takes values from a to b, where a and b are finite. X follows a given distribution Function 'F'. Suppose that g(X) is a continuous and differentiable function. E.g., g=k*X, where k is a positive constant.

I am trying to compute E(g(X)|X<=x0), where x0<b. I know X<=x0 because a given event has occurred that excludes some interval of values from the support of the original distribution function.

In the example above, is the solution the integral from a to x0 of g(x).f(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_{X|X<x_0}(t)=\frac{1}{F_X(x_0)}f_X(t)\mathbb{1}_{[a;x_0]}(t)$$

thus your expctation becomes

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X<x_0]=\frac{1}{F_X(x_0)}\int_{a}^{x_0}g(x)f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: Thanks, Tommik. You divide the density function by Fx because of the conditional probability definition, right? the numerator of P(A|B) definition is 1, while the denominator is the distribution function

Comment: @my2cents ; aahhh....that's right, $\int_a^{x_0}$. Amended. Dividing by $F_X(x_0)$ is due to the conditional density I showed

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @my2cents : Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: done! thanks, I didn't know it!